# The least relation which produces a partial order

Tags: order-theory

Fix some set $U$. Let $E$ be a binary relation on $U$.

By definition $S(E)=\operatorname{id}_U \cup E \cup E^2 \cup E^3 \cup\dots$.

I define $\mu(E) = \bigcap \{X\in\mathscr{P}(U\times U) \mid S(X)=E \}$. That, informally speaking, is $\mu(E)$ is the least relation $X$ which produces $E$.

Question: Is $S(\mu(E)) = E$ for every partial order $E$?

If the question is false, does it become true if we consider only these $X$ which are partial orders themselves?

Comment: What do you mean by $E^2$?

Comment: In other words, your $S(E)$ is just the reflexive transitive envelope of $E$.

Comment: @PedroM. $E^2 = E\circ E$ is the composition of binary relation $E$ with itself

Comment: Are you sure you are asking what you mean in the second question? If $X$ is already a partial order then $S(X)=X$, so if $\mu(E)$ only takes those into account we get $\mu(E)=E$ trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no: it can happen that $S(\mu(E))\neq E$.
$\newcommand{\X}{\mathrel{X}}\newcommand{\E}{\mathrel{E}}$

As a counterexample, consider the usual ordering on $\mathbb{Q}$ (in fact any dense linear order will do). I claim that $\mu(\leq)=\emptyset$. To see this, let $a< b$ be rational numbers and $X=\,\leq\!\setminus\{(a,b)\}$. We get $S(X)=\,\leq$, since $a\X c\X b$ for any rational $a<c<b$, which puts $(a,b)$ into $S(X)$. So $X$ is one of the relations considered when computing $\mu(\leq)$, which means that $(a,b)\notin\mu(\leq)$.

As $\mu(\leq)=\emptyset$, it is now clear that $S(\mu(\leq))$ is the identity relation and, in particular, not equal to $\leq$.

---

**Update:** This is a fun problem. Here is a characterization of when your conclusion is true for linear orders.

A piece of notation, if $E$ is a partial order, I use $a\uparrow=\{b;a\E b\}$ for the cone above $a$ and $a\downarrow= \{b;b\E a\}$ for the cone below $a$. I also write $E^*$ for the reverse order.

**Theorem:** Let $E$ be a linear order. The following are equivalent:

1. $S(\mu(E))=E$;
2. $E$ does not admit suborders of type $\omega+1$ or $(\omega+1)^*$;
3. For any $a$, the cones $a\uparrow$ and $a\downarrow$ are well-ordered by $E$ and $E^*$, respectively;
4. $E$ embeds into $\mathbb{Z}$.

*Proof:*

($1\implies 2$): Suppose that $E$ has a suborder of type $\omega+1$ (the other case is similar). Enumerate this suborder as $a_0\E a_1\E \dots\E a_\omega$. For any $n$ let $E_n=E\setminus\{(a_n,a_\omega)\}$ and observe that $S(E_n)=E$. It follows that $(a_n,a_\omega)\notin \mu(E)$ for any $n$ and therefore $(a_n,a_\omega)\notin S(\mu(E))$ for any $n$.

($2\implies 3$): Clear.

($3\implies 4$): Assuming $E$ is nonempty, pick any $a$ and map it to $0$. Since the cones $a\uparrow$ and $a\downarrow$ are well-ordered, $a$ has an immediate $E$-successor and $E$-predecessor. Map these to $1$ and $-1$, respectively. Continue inductively. Note that we never run out of room, since any element we could not find an image for would have to have one of its two cones illfounded.

($4\implies 1$): For any $a$ let $a^-$ and $a^+$ be its immediate predecessor and successor, respectively. Observe that if $X$ is any relation such that $S(X)=E$ then $(a^-,a),(a,a^+)\in X$ for any $a$. Thus all these pairs are in $\mu(E)$ and it follows (since any two points of $\mathbb{Z}$ have finite distance) that $S(\mu(E))=E$. $\square$

The situation with partial orders seems to be less clear. For example, there are illfounded partial orders $E$ such that $S(\mu(E))=E$; take for example a copy of $(\omega+1)^*$ and on the side insert a single point between each $n$ and $\omega$.

Comment: Great solution! I think, however, that to get that $(a,b) \notin \mu(\leq)$ you did not have to create both the $c$'s and the $e$'s, by reasoning as follows: if $(a,b) \notin X$, then $(a,b) \notin \mu(\leq)$ by definition; otherwise, take a rational number $a < d < b$ and reason as you did to see that $S(X \setminus \{(a,b)\}) = \leq$.

Comment: @PedroM. Yes, you are right. The only thing I needed was to find an $X$ which omits a given pair of rationals. I have edited the argument.

Comment: (stupid comment removed)